# Edit Custom Database Tables in Wordpress

Tags: custom-field, customization, database

I have a site that uses custom database tables to manage info that is inserted by a process completely independent from Wordpress. The data from the table is used in the Wordpress site but it is not manageable through the Admin interface.

I want to make it manageable via the admin backend. What is the basic process for this? In my mind I need to create a link in the Admin sidebar to "Manage Custom Data" and that link opens up a page that permits basic CRUD management of the various rows in the table.

This would be effortlessly simply in vanilla code but I am not familiar with such custom aspects of modifying Wordpress so I am just looking for pointing in the right direction. Give me the big picture, in other words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes before: This is only *how I'd approach it* - I'm not going to step more into detail, because basically it's a list of plugins you'll have to code.

## Build a Back-End page

Use the function [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) to add a page. Then build your management tables extending the [`WP_List_Table`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) class:

```
class WPSE_48824_List_Table extends WP_List_Table
{
    // do stuff
}

// Use it:
$list_table = new WPSE_48824_List_Table();
$list_table->display();
```

## Handling the DB

Basically you're going to have a lot of DB requests. Use the [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) object/Class.

Don't forget to [`$wpdb->prepare()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples_2) your data before inserting it.

Also make use of `$wpdb->prefix` instead of hardcoding it.

## Bulk actions

Will run via Ajax. More can be read [on Ajax for Plugins in Code](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or here on WPSE in the tag archive [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

Comment: I don't recommend that you sink a lot of time into extending `WP_List_Table` - it's marked private, and I've been told by core devs that in the future, extending classes may just break. I have some fancy classes that help with manually displaying content in a WPish way: https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/boones-sortable-columns/ https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/boones-pagination/ Other than that minor point, +1 to what kaiser says.

Comment: Core devs do say a lot of stuff on long days. We got functions or func args that are deprecated since years and still functional. `WP_List_Table` won't break in the future for one reason: Too many plugins & Themes are relying on it and it's pretty well documented (Only god knows who's the one who took a day of to write this. Just praise him!). But thanks for linking your plugins.

Comment: Incidentally, the WP_List_Table [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) now explicitly says "This class may be used by developers through extending the class and overriding its methods", so this is definitely a supported solution these days.

Comment: @MattGibson Thanks for coming back to an old question/answer. Updated and extended with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/db-toolkit/

I've not yet used it to it's full potential but it allows CRUD management of data in your database. Its completely managable in the Wordpress backend. Although there is a bit of a learning curve to it the interface is nice and should do exactly what you need.

Comment: This plugin is no longer available.